# C# WPF - Long Operation On Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous

I have `Button`, which calls another method on click.
The other method performs an operation which can take a long time...
So I thought to create a `Label` which appears on the start of the operation and tells the user to wait, after the operation is complete, the `Label` will disappear. The only problem is that because the `Button` is a `UI` element (that is what I think the reason is), the calls to change the `Label` inside the `Button` click only activate after the `Button` click is complete... (so basically the `Label` was invisible before the click and cannot change during it, so it stays that way).

Here is my code:

```
private void SearchButtonActions()
{
        UI.InvokeA(() => lstFiles.ItemsSource = FDItems);
        bool SearchAndListing = false;
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Height = double.NaN);
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Content = "Search Started...");
        int index = cbTypes.SelectedIndex;
        string selecteditem = cbSearchOption.SelectedItem.ToString();
        SearchAndListing = FD.Search(index, selecteditem);
        FDItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(FD.Items);
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Height = 0);
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden);
        //UI.InvokeA(() => lblWait.Content = "Search Ended.");
        if (SearchAndListing)
        {
            UI.InvokeA(() => lstFiles.ItemsSource = FDItems);
            UI.InvokeA(() => lblCount.Content = string.Format("Items: {0}", FDItems.Count));
        }
}
```

I am talking about the methods to change the `lblWait`...
btw: `UI.Invoke` - is a shortcut to `Dispatcher.Current.InvokeAsync(Action)`

I have tried using `Tasks`, `BackGroundWorker`, and changing the `UI.Invoke` to `Invoke` (`synchronically` instead of `asynchronically`), and all didn't work out...

Can someone help?

Comment: Use task.run and progressbar

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue before and never gave much thought to it until now.

Your argument is correct the UI thread is currently running the Click method so it is busy and will not run any thing else.

even when using the dispatcher it is still performing the click method so the ui thread would pop the next delegate to run only when it's done.

So this wouldn't work :

```
   lbl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

And this wouldn't work :

```
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => lbl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Thread.Sleep(3000));
```

What would work is dispatching the ui operations from a background thread.

XAML :

```
    <StackPanel>   
       <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click"/>
       <Label x:Name="lbl" Content="Label" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="Red" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
     </StackPanel>
```

CS :

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => 
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Visibility");
            lbl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;                
        });

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Thread.Sleep(3000));
        });            
    }
```

FYI : your probably wondering why i do not propagate the Visibility value to the UI thread using the dispatcher. This is because each DispatcherObject ( our DependencyObject derived from DispatcherObject) propagates execution to it's associated Dispatcher.

Comment: I have tried to modify it like you told me here... but it didn't work as well... how can I show you the new code? (it says here that it's too long...)

Comment: can u share it with me on google docs ? 

eranotz50@gmail.com 
ill see it tommrow , good night

Comment: I will send the doc to your email

Comment: any if anyone else wants to see here is the link:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gJaT5MnNrSXc1Nl_Pj81B0fIvF_j-YfNaH_5hdmV0OI/pub

Comment: @David47 i'm sorry i google docs is blocked at my work place for some reason. could you send me an email with it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Show your "please wait label" as soon as you click the button.
2. Execute your long operation: `FD.Search(index, selecteditem);` in an async `Task.Run()`
3. Use `ContinueWith()` to hide the label once the long operation is complete.

   ```
   private void SearchButtonActions() {
       lblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
       Task.Run(() => {
           return FD.Search(index, selecteditem);
       }).ContinueWith((Task<bool> task) => {
           Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { 
             FDItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>(FD.Items));
             lblWait.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
           });
       });
   }
   ```

If you need the result of `FD.Search()` somewhere in the `ContinueWith()` block, use `task.Result` to retrieve it.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: That exception just means you have to use the dispatcher to invoke the method that threw the exception. The UI thread owns all the WPF controls. The Task runs on a different thread.

Comment: I fixed this exception, an I ran into another problem... I think for some reason the second or even the first task do not get executed because the label shows but then it stucks... even if the in the case of operation it is considerably very fast... (it stays after the operation should have been completed)...

Comment: @David47 hmm, ok. Is there any way I could take a look at your project? I think it's probably a simple issue, I just don't have all the context.

Comment: do you have skype? we could have a private chat there and I could send you whatever you need... (add me dudushnaider)

Comment: @David47 I do, I'll add you this evening when I get home.